# Unable to load google map tiles from secure connection and GMSTileURLConstructor

Tags: ios, google-maps, ssl

I am attempting to load map tiles from an SSL URL. My code to load the tiles is as follows:

```
func initializeTiles() {
    let urlInfo:GMSTileURLConstructor = { (x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> URL in 
        let baseUrl = Constants.MAPS_BASE_URL
        let tileUrl = "\(baseUrl)ImageryMaps&channel=1006&version=1&x=\(x)&y=\(y)&z=\(zoom)&is2d=t"
        return URL(string: tileUrl)!
    }

    let layer = GMSURLTileLayer(urlConstructor: urlInfo)
    if mapView != nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            layer.zIndex = 100
            layer.tileSize = 512
            layer.map = self.mapView
        }
    }
}
```

This code has been tested with non-secure urls and loads tiles successfully. When using this code with an SSL url I am getting the following:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

I've read many posts regarding this error and most seem to point to making changes to the info.plist file. I have already made the appropriate changes to the plist and the results are the same error. Here are the settings I have added to the plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xxxxxxx.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I have run out of options or ideas of things to try. Making changes to the info.plist seems to have absolutely no effect on the app.

Can anyone suggest something else to try here? Thanks!